# How to build vim GUI version with GTK

Tags: compile-vim

I pulled all the source files, and then ran the following command to configure and tried to build vim with GUI support:

```
/configure --enable-gui=auto
```

Here is some more information:

```
checking --enable-gui argument... yes/auto - automatic GUI support
checking whether or not to look for GTK+ 2... yes
checking --disable-gtktest argument... gtk test enabled
checking for location of Motif GUI includes... <not found>
```

But the vim I compiled still doesn't support GUI.

```
vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jul  6 2018 16:24:24)
Included patches: 1-155
Compiled by coeus@debian9
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
```

I am using Debian Stretch. Can anyone help me?

I tried to follow up with INSTALL file, but it seems it doesn't work, and there are no error messages mentioning the GUI is not compiled... Very strange.

Comment: I think there is a Debian package of vim with gui called vim-gtk. I would definitely try it before compiling my own. Edit: In fact, there are several (vim-gnome, vim-athena, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you don't have the needed libraries installed on your system to build a gui.  If you read the file [`src/INSTALL`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/INSTALL#L88-L134) it explains the different `--enable-gui` options.

For example for me I could run `./configure --enable-gui=kde && make` just fine but the resulting vim did not have a gui. When I checked `./configure --enable-gui=kde | grep gui` I found that

```
checking --enable-gui argument... Sorry, kde GUI is not supported
```

Only when I ran `./configure --enable-gui=gtk2 --with-features=huge && make && src/vim -g` it worked properly.

**Bottom line:** check the output of the configure script and find out if you have the needed libs.

Comment: I just do this again as your said: 

    $ ./configure --enable-gui=gtk2 | grep -i "g[tu][ki]"
    checking --enable-gui argument... GTK+ 2.x GUI support
    checking --disable-gtktest argument... gtk test enabled

But when run the make, there is still no GUI support. Which file I should check for details?

Comment: If `--enable-fail-if-missing` is added to the `./configure` step, it fails if dependencies are missing. That can help to detect this kind of issue.